# linq to sql transaction exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql, transactions

i getting this error message from my transaction code, and there is no other transaction uncompleted

> The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are
>   pending requests working on this transaction.

```
TransactionScope tran = null;
    using (tran = new TransactionScope())
    {
        try
        {
            string resNumber = repoKontrat.KontratNoUret(kontratTipi); //procedure
            _seciliKontrat.ID = repoKontrat.KaydetID(seciliKontrat);//insertOnSubmit()
            repoKontratKalem.KaydetProc(
                                _seciliKontrat.ID,
                                await repoKontratKalem.Getir_Table(gridKontratKalemler.ToList()),
                                digerKalemleriDegistir //bool
                                ); // procedure
            gp.Kaydet(_seciliKontrat.ID, gp.KontratGpTahminiveGercekHesapla(_seciliKontrat.ID));//insertOnSubmit()

            gp.Kaydet(_seciliKontrat.ID, gp.KontratGpTahminiveGercekHesapla(_seciliKontrat.ID));//procedure

            repoKontrat.SatisKontratiFirmaBilgileriniGuncelle(_seciliKontrat.ID);//procedure
                                                                                 //-----
            foreach (var item in silinenKasaKayitlari)
            {
                repoCariHareketler.Sil(Convert.ToInt32(item));//insertOnSubmit()
            }
            repoCariHareketler.Kaydet(_seciliKontrat.ID, await repoCariHareketler.Getir_Table(gridKontratKasa.ToList()));//insertOnSubmit()
            tran.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            tran = null;
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of methods repoCariHareketler.Kaydet   and others?

Comment: Maybe you should translate your code into English so the method names at least give us some idea what happens here. That said, it seems that the stored procedures (which I thing "procedure" means) also open and commit transactions.